# Nexus 7 no longer detected in Ubuntu after flashing recovery image

Tags: android, ubuntu, cyanogenmod

This is hands-down the most esoteric question I've ever posed on this site, but here goes:

Following the instructions on [Cyanogen Mod's site](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_grouper) I was able to make it as far as flashing the linked recovery image.

However, now that I've done that, Ubuntu no longer recognizes or mounts the device, so I can't proceed to the next step.

I'm at a loss as to what to do at this point, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your device's `vendorId` to `home/.android/adb_usb.ini` file and then restart the `adb server`. If that doesn't works, please reboot your system and connect your device to a different port and check. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Ultimately I got things working using WugFresh's Nexus Root Toolkit.